# Выделение памяти List C#

Tags: c#

Краткий, может быть глупый вопрос: **как при создании List<тип> выделить сразу память под n Элементов?** Конструктор позволяет задать только примерную емкость, но без выделения.

Если так сделать нельзя, то как тогда? Я хочу за 1 строку выделить память под n элементов, используя скажем addRange(INumerable...).

**Что то слышал, про однострочники с использованием лямбда выражений, они как-то могут тут помочь или же их используют только при сортировке/выборе элементов?** Подскажите пожалуйста. Не пинайте) , хотя нет, лучше пинайте:)

P.S еще мне требуется выделить память под List< List< Тип > > , если также можно, то напишите)

Comment: @Bulson это не выделяет память под элементы, я же хочу взять после создания объекта и писать например list[i] = 5;

Comment: вы путаете с массивом, при создании списка даже с конструктором по-умолчанию он сразу "готов к работе"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В конструкторе вы задаёте точную *ёмкость*: количество элементов, такое, что увеличение размера списка до этого количества не вызывает повторной аллокации, и поэтому быстрое. Вам по идее не должно хотеться создать список с значениями по умолчанию, это скорее всего лишено смысла.

Но если очень хочется, можно

- так: `new T[n].ToList()`
- или [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466974/276994):

  ```
  List<T> list = new List<T>(n);
  list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(default(T), n));
  ```
- или так: `Enumerable.Repeat(default(T), n).ToList()` (вариант @VadimOvchinnikov из комментариев)

Comment: *Вам по идее не должно хотеться создать список с значениями по умолчанию, это скорее всего лишено смысла* Это было бы приемлимо, я думаю, конкретно в моем случае, количество элементов не велико

Comment: Гуд! То что нужно), спасибо

Comment: @Xambey: Значение по умолчанию лишено обычно смысла, как только у вас есть реально нужное значение, вы по идее можете в этот момент добавить его.

Comment: @Xambey: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.

Comment: @VladD Я вот в этом слабо улавливаю смысл: "Вам по идее не должно хотеться создать список с значениями по умолчанию...", а почему мне должно хотеться все время указывать точный размер?

Comment: @Bulson: Ну, capacity можно достаточно часто предсказать, но если значение ещё не известно, то класть вместо него малоосмысленное значение по умолчанию, то обращение к не тому элементу не приведёт к исключению.

Comment: @VladD, т.е. вы хотите сказать, что практикуете явное указание кол-во элементов? В случае массивов без этого не обойтись, но в случае типизированных коллекций, я такое встречаю впервые.

Comment: @Bulson: Наоборот, если у меня ещё неизвестны нужные значения, я оставляю размер нулевым.

Comment: @VladD, а ну, ОК

Comment: @VladD А не проще было бы `Enumerable.Repeat(default(T), n).ToList()`? A то `AddRange` кажется неуместным.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Тоже хороший вариант, кстати. У меня есть похожий `new T[n].ToList()`.

Comment: @VladD да я вижу, я просто за второй `List<T> list = new List<T>(n);` `list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(default(T), n));`. Его просто можно упростить и всё (по-моему, он избыточен), в этом суть моего предложения.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Тут ещё вопрос в эффективности. Вариант с `ToList` проводит реаллокации при добавлении, т. к. `ToList` не знает целевого размера и вызывает в цикле `Add` (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,98).